# Display external webpage into a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 HTML files (both in the same directory). How can I display content of one into another?

I can think of these ways:

1. Create `XMLHTTPRequest`. Fetch the HTML file and display in
   appropriate location.
2. Use `iframes`

What are others methods to diplay external HTML file?

Comment: why do you want to know more ways? Isn't it good enough?

Comment: @genesis: What is the harm in knowing more ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have three options to do this.

How do you even have proposed two:

- *Using only HTML*, you need to do it with `iframe`. Your user will need to make 2 http requests to load 2 html files.
- *Using only HTML and JavaScript*, you also can work with `XMLHTTPRequest` or some JavaScript framework (like jQuery) to do that Ajax to you. Your users will need to make 2 http requests also, but SEO will be a problem in this case.

The third option, like others have suggested, is:

- *Using a server side processing*, like the suggested `PHP include` or `ASP.NET UserControl`.  **I think it's the best approach** since the user will never know you have 2 files to show that page and also will need only 1 http request. And better for SEO crawlers too.

As an ASP.NET programmer, I personally like to have a base `aspx` page and split its sections using the UserControls `ascx`. The generated html remain clean in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use server-side proxy. However, I'd personally use these iframes

Answer (score 0):

If your host supports PHP then you can make the containing HTML file into a PHP file and include the other one with `include()`.  This is exactly the reason I learned PHP in the first place.